# Visual Studio DAC with Schemabound View containing hierarchyid::GetRoot() - Two part name needed?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-clr

In Visual Studio, when trying to create a DAC which has a schemabound view which contains hierarchyid::GetRoot() this error is generated and the project does not build.  However, the t-sql is ok as if I create the view directly in the database it works ok.

Is there a two part name for hierarchyid to solve this?

In a DAC project is VS:

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
with schemabinding
    AS SELECT hierarchyid::GetRoot() as t

Gives:

Error   93  SQL70561: Cannot schema bind view '[dbo].[View1]' because name 'hierarchyid' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with DACs themselves -- I don't think it recognizes this as valid syntax. DACs don't support all features in SQL Server, and this appears to be one of them.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced, it's what I initially thought, however, if you remove schemabinding then its ok.  DAC 2.0 supports hierarchyId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to add sys. in front of the hierarchyId:

sys.hierarchyid::GetRoot()

Comment: Ah, yes. This makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of prerequisites to use the SCHEMABINDING option:

·         You cannot use * in the SELECT clause in the query, you have to specify column names

·         You have to use two-part naming convention when referring to objects (which is in  general a good practice)

So, you need to use schema name always when referring to objects when you want to use the SCHEMABINDING option, in this case sys.hierarchyid